# MAX in SPARQL 1.1?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am a beginner at SPARQL 1.1. I have an N-Triples file like below. I want to find the maximum value for `Work_RVU` (the last attribute) and the related code (the 4th attribute).

```
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns?#type> <http://cms.gov/HCPCS> .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Remove ear lesion" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Status_Code> "A" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Code> "69540" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Work_RVU> "1.25" .

<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns?#type> <http://cms.gov/HCPCS> .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Remove ear lesion" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Status_Code> "A" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Code> "69550" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Work_RVU> "11.15" .

<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns?#type> <http://cms.gov/HCPCS> .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Remove ear lesion" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Status_Code> "A" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Code> "69552" .
<file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#Work_RVU> "19.81" .
```

The maximum RVU should be 19.81 and the code should be “69552”. I could print 19.81 but always print “69540”, which means it always selects the first code it meets each time.

My SPARQL code is below:

```
PREFIX pre: <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#>
SELECT ?code (MAX (?val) AS ?Max_RVU)
WHERE{
    ?code pre:Work_RVU ?val .
}
```

Is there a mistake in this query? I also tried another query,

```
PREFIX pre: <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#>
PREFIX head: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns?#>
SELECT ?code (MAX (?val) AS ?Max_RVU)
WHERE{
    ?d head:type <http://cms.gov/HCPCS> .
    ?d pre:Code ?code .
    ?d pre:Work_RVU ?val .
}
```

but the result was the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior that you describe.  When I try run either of the queries on your data with Jena's ARQ, I get an error:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.nt 
Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?code
```

However, this is easily remedied.  Adding `GROUP BY ?code` to your first query gives output closer to what you want, I think.

```
PREFIX pre: <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#>

SELECT ?code (MAX (?val) AS ?Max_RVU)
WHERE {
    ?code pre:Work_RVU ?val .
}
GROUP BY ?code
```

This means that the results that match the matter are partitioned by their group, and then of all the `pre:Work_RVU` values associated with a `?code`, the maximum is selected in the output for the code.  The output looks like this:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.nt 
-----------------------------------------
| code                        | Max_RVU |
=========================================
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> | "1.25"  |
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> | "11.15" |
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> | "19.81" |
-----------------------------------------
```

This does, indeed, show the maximum value associated with each code. However, since each of the codes in the data has only one RVU value, I wonder if what you are looking for isn't actually the code that has, of all the codes, the maximum RVU value.  If this is the case, you can do it by selecting codes and their RVUs, *ordering* by RVU, and selecting just the first of the results.  For instance, we can order by `?val` in descending order with this query:

```
PREFIX pre: <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#>

SELECT ?code ?val 
WHERE {
    ?code pre:Work_RVU ?val .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?val)
```

which produces

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.nt 
-----------------------------------------
| code                        | val     |
=========================================
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> | "19.81" |
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69550> | "11.15" |
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69540> | "1.25"  |
-----------------------------------------
```

You probably only want the first of those lines, so we add `LIMIT 1`:

```
PREFIX pre: <file://PPRVU12.xlsx#>

SELECT ?code ?val 
WHERE {
    ?code pre:Work_RVU ?val .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?val)
LIMIT 1
```

which produces

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.nt 
-----------------------------------------
| code                        | val     |
=========================================
| <file://PPRVU12.xlsx/69552> | "19.81" |
-----------------------------------------
```

You may run into the problem that your RVU values are being stored as strings, which means that the ordering you are getting from the SPARQL query is not a numeric ordering, but a lexical ordering.  The best solution would be to clean up your data so that it actually contains numbers.  However, as long as you're just trying to get the maximal value, and the strings all have the same formatting, you'll still get the result you want, because higher values will need longer strings, and the lexical ordering of the digit characters is consistent with the numeric ordering of the digits.

Comment: @YuchunCui Did this answer end up working out for you?  If it did, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225437) to let others know that it worked for you (and to reward the answerer with a bit of reputation, too)!

Comment: @Joshua Taylor Thanks that really helped a lot. Sorry for the late accept!